# How to save space and time with a mirrored NxN array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an N x N array of numbers, with the property that the [ i ][ j ] number is always equal to the [ j ][ i ] number. Ie:

```
[ 0 3 9 2 ]
[ 3 0 5 6 ]
[ 9 5 0 1 ]
[ 2 6 1 0 ]
```

Is there a representation I can use to save space and time in accessing elements? It would cut the array size in half, and if possible, reduce the cache miss penalty by indexing [ i ][ j ] and [ j ][ i ] to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using a one dimensional array, you should save space, and there might be some slight change in access time, though whether it is faster or not, it probably depends on the compiler and the language.

I wrote this solution quickly in Qt, but it should be simple to convert it to stl c++ or some other language:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

class MirroredArray
{
public:
    MirroredArray(int sideLength)
    {
        values.fill(0, sideLength*(sideLength+1)/2);
        this->s = sideLength;
    }

    int get(int r, int c)
    {
        if(c > r)
        {
          return values.at(s*r-(r-1)*r/2 + c-r);
        }
        else
        {
          return values.at(s*c-(c-1)*c/2 + r-c);
        }
    }

    void set(int r, int c, int value)
    {
        if(c > r)
        {
          values[s*r-(r-1)*r/2 + c-r] = value;
        }
        else
        {
          values[s*c-(c-1)*c/2 + r-c] = value;
        }
    }
    int getSide()
    {
        return s;
    }

    QString contentsToString()
    {
        QString temp = "(" + QString::number(values.size()) + ") - ";
        for(int i = 0; i<values.size(); i++)
          temp += QString::number(i) + ", ";
        return temp;
    }

private:
    QVector <int> values;
    int s;
};
```

Note: This code doesn't do any error checking that you are passing in a valid row and column value.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with a one dimensional array is that I am working with large enough data sets that a single chunk of allocation is highly likely to fail. I can adapt this to a multi-dimensional array however.

Comment: When deriving this, you use and reuse this formula: the sum of 1 to n is n*(n+1)/2.  If you look at the calls, it has a variation where you set n = m-1 and you get (m-1)*m/2 as the sum of 1 to m-1.  See also [How to Sum the Integers from 1 to N](http://www.wikihow.com/Sum-the-Integers-from-1-to-N)

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the elements in a one dimensional array like this:

```
01234  (n=5)
 5678
  901
   23
    4
```

The position in the array is `(n + (n-y+1))*y/2 + (x-y)`.

If `x<y` then swap the two coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, could you explain how you derived that formula? Parts of it look very similar to the functions I was trying but I'd like to see the whole picture.

Comment: the first part is the sum for arithmetic series (rows previous to y) S_n=(a_1+a_n)*n/2, the second part is the position in the row y. note: for faster calculation you can simplify it a bit by moving -y to the first term.